# How to add Lua functions to the Notepad++ functionList.XML

Tags: xml, regex, lua, notepad++

Notepad++ provides a function list.

I'm currently using Notepad++ 6.5

functionList.xml defines parsers for function names using regular expressions.

The following code defines the parser for c functions

```
<parser id="c_function" displayName="C source" commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(//.*?$))">
    <function
        mainExpr="^[\t ]*((static|const|virtual)[\s]+)?[\w:]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+)([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\)\(]*\)([\s]*const[\s]*)?[\n\s]*\{"
        displayMode="$functionName">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_~]+[\s]*\("/>
                <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_~]+"/>
                </functionName>         </function>
</parser>
```

I tried my regex online and everything was fine. But it does not work for the functionList.xml somehow. The function list stays empty.

How would this look like for a Lua function?

Here's my try:

```
<parser id="lua_function" displayName="Lua Function" commentExpr="((--\[\[\*.*?\*)/|(--.*[\n\s\w\t]*\]\]))">
            <function
                mainExpr="^[\t\s]*(function)[\s]+[\w]+\("
                displayMode="$functionName">
                <functionName>
                    <nameExpr expr="(?:(function[\s]+))[\w]+"/>
                </functionName>
            </function>
        </parser>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use my own definition for Notepad++. It's main difference is supporting of functions like:`local SomeFunction = function() end` and `function SomeObject:Func() end`. Also it has some basic lua table view compatibilitites.

```
<!-- Basic lua parser for functionList.xml in Notepad++ 6.5.3 -->
<!-- See http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html -->
<parser id="lua_function" displayName="Lua" commentExpr="--.*?$">
    <!-- Basic lua table view, nested lua table not supported -->
    <classRange
        mainExpr="[.\w]+[\s]*=[\s]*\{"
        openSymbole="\{"
        closeSymbole="\}"
        displayMode="node">
        <className>
            <nameExpr expr="[.\w]+"/>
        </className>
        <function
            mainExpr="[.\w]+[\s]*=[\s]*['&quot;]?[\w]+['&quot;]?">
            <functionName>
                <funcNameExpr expr=".*"/>
            </functionName>
        </function>
    </classRange>
    <!-- Basic lua functions support -->
    <function 
        mainExpr="(function[\s]+[.\w]+(:[\w]+)?)|([.\w]+[\s]*=[\s]*function)"
        displayMode="$className->$functionName">
        <functionName>
            <nameExpr expr="((?<=function)[\s]+[.:\w]+)|(([.\w]+)(?=([\s]*=[\s]*function)))"/>
        </functionName>
        <className>
            <nameExpr expr="[.\w]+(?=:)"/>
        </className>
    </function>
</parser>
```

Also add association

```
<association id="lua_function" langID="23" />
```

Comment: Why are you using a character class for a single character? `[\s]*` is the same as `\s*`

Answer (score 2):

Two things i have experienced with lua and functions list is that i first have to use functionList.xml inside %appdata%\Notepad++ for it to work, but that could be my installation
second is that whats missing from your configruations is 2 things. First the association langID = "23"

```
<associationMap>
  <association langID = "23" id="lua_function"/>
</associationMap>
```

second being regexp will miss local functions, mine currently looks like this

```
        <parser id="lua_function" displayName="Lua">
            <function mainExpr="^[\t|local\s]*function\s+[^0-9][_A-Za-z0-9]+\s*\("
                      displayMode="$functionName">
              <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="[^0-9][_A-Za-z0-9]+\s*\("/>
                <nameExpr expr="[^0-9][_A-Za-z0-9]+"/>
              </functionName>
            </function>
         </parser>
```

adding both to functionList.xml (depending on installation, program files or %appdata%) will make functionlist work for lua language inside Notepad++ 6.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I got the following to work. It is pretty simple and I did not bother with the `commentExpr` attribute (as it's optional anyway; see the [documentation](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
  <functionList>
    <associationMap>
      <association langID = "23" id="lua_function"/>
    </associationMap>
    <parsers>
      <parser id="lua_function" displayName="Lua">
        <function mainExpr="^[\t\s]*function\s+[^0-9][_A-Za-z0-9]+\s*\("
                  displayMode="$functionName">
          <functionName>
            <nameExpr expr="[^0-9][_A-Za-z0-9]+\s*\("/>
            <nameExpr expr="[^0-9][_A-Za-z0-9]+"/>
          </functionName>
        </function>
      </parser>
    </parsers>
  </functionList>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Did you make sure to add your parser to the `associationMap` tag?

The multiple `nameExpr` tags are needed to filter a matching string to only the function name.

Answer (score -1):

Snippet from [FunctionList Plugin 2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Function%20List/FunctionList%20Plugin%20v2.1/):

```
<Language name="Lua" imagelistpath="">
    <CommList param1='&quot;' param2='&quot;' />
    <CommList param1="&apos;" param2="&apos;" />
    <CommList param1="--" param2="" />
    <CommList param1="--\[\[" param2="\]\]" />
    <Group name="FUNCTION" subgroup="" icon="0" child="0" autoexp="0" matchcase="1" fendtobbeg="" bbegtobend="\&lt;do\&gt;|\&lt;if\&gt;|\&lt;function\&gt;" keywords="">
        <Rules regexbeg="^[-\s]*function\s+" regexfunc="[\w_:.]+" regexend="\s*\([\w_,.\s]*\)" bodybegin="" bodyend="\&lt;end\&gt;" sep="" />
        <Rules regexbeg="^[-\s]*" regexfunc="[\w_:.]+" regexend="\s*=\s*function\s*\([\w_,\s]*\)" bodybegin="" bodyend="\&lt;end\&gt;" sep="" />
        <Rules regexbeg="^" regexfunc="[\w_]+" regexend="\s*=" bodybegin="\{" bodyend="\}" sep="" />
    </Group>
</Language>
```

I guess, You could just grab up-to-date version of that plugin and not to worry anymore... :)

Comment: That plugin is depreciated and crashes Notepad++ in my experience.

Comment: @tomcat23, could You please be a bit more precise with the Notepad++ versions You're using?

Comment: I was using the latest version, v6.9.2 on Win10 x64. I used the plugin manager and selected 'unstable' plugins to see/install it. Had to delete the dll in the plugins directory before I could get Notepad++ to launch without crashing.

Wasn't able to get a function list for Lua working at all with the code from any of the answers here. I finally gave up.

Comment: @tomcat23, please, note that the question was about Notepad 6.5 specifically.